# Auto Number in Quote

Tags: auto-number

I want to create 2 diferente autonumbers on Quote for two diferent Record Types.

It is possible to do this action on Process Builder with the Condition PriorValue?

E create 2 new Field (type number) 1 for each record type in order to Store this information.

It is possible or the only wau to do is with Custom Settings e Triggers?

Tks for the help.

Comment: This question's been asked quite a bit. I've linked three samples of previous questions that cover this territory. I suggest searching "record type autonumber" for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Autonumber is generated by internal database, it cannot be controlled by any standard/ custom process.

But, you can have 2 auto number fields which will be generated for all the records and a text field(unique). In the workflow or process builder, you can check the record type of the case and populated necessary auto number field to text field.

Comment: But in that case when i create a Record regardless the REcord tyoe the 2 new Autonumbers field will received number right?

I want if it is possible  only get a number for the record type i create...

Comment: Based on record type you cannot have auto number field populated since it is generated by internal database